# MySQL PHP Dynamic Data Select/Write

Tags: php, mysql

This is more of a design question, on the best way to do this.

I am trying to build an "inventorying" application into my project. I need to allow people to add an unlimited amount of sub-data.

Right now I'm unable to determine the best way to be able to store data as searchable (so I think blob is out). I dynamically store what they call `param1->param2->param3->param4` such as `Box Row Section` in a BLOB because there will only be one schema per user.

I'm storing the data on the location that needs to be searchable so if I have to look for `param1=1,param2=2,param3=3` I can find it easily. I currently can search the column storing it as a plain text array with LIKE or REGEX, is that the best way to do this?

Example:

```
User 1 - Box 1
User 2 - Box 1 Row 3
User 3 - Box 1 Row 3 Section 4
User 4 - Box 1 Row 3 Section 4 Cell 7
User 5 - Warehouse 42 Isle 4 Shelf 4 Position 13
```

This is what I have so far:

```
- inventory (TABLE)
id INT(10)
itemid MEDIUMINT(7)
userid INT(10)
inventorylocation INT(10)
amount INT(10)
- inventorylabels (TABLE)
id INT(10)
userid INT(10)
schema BLOB(65535)
- inventorylocation (TABLE)
id INT(10)
location MEDIUMTEXT(16777215)
```

[MySQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f907d/14)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would setup the table like this:

```
| id | user_id | param | sequence |
```

Put the order of the parameters in sequence (so just count 1,2,3,etc.) Then do a recursive query for each param.

Comment: So a single entry would be multiple rows? I don't think that would scale, well. Would it?

Comment: Why not @AndrewWilson? It's what a database is built for isn't it? In terms of normalisation i think there is nothing wrong with doing it this way...